# Weird artifact/cube shapes when I put flame shader on imported vdb

Tags: shaders, volumetrics

I've been seeing these weird cube shapes when I import an embergen vdb and the flames run out, via clicking on the flame attribute channel.
details: it only happens after all the flames in the flames attribute are gone, and only happens on gpu compute(im on an amd gpu maybe thats the problem) and it also has only happened on imported vdbs so far not with mantaflow vdbs as they dont have the flames attribute. I've also tested multiple shaders that still use the flames attribute and they all don't work when I use the flames attribute as the tempature, happens in render and material preview in viewport and in final render.

my shader should be only showing the smoke right now as all the flames are gone yet it shows this
[image: image of the issue happening]

Any ideas on how to fix or why its happening?

I've tested multiple vdbs and nothing has fixed it, I use the flame attribute in my temperature attribute for the flame shading, cycles, gpu compute and it works fine on cpu compute for some reason(only problem being its slow, like slower than just using mantaflow)
[image: example of working shader]
example of working shader

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since it is very likely a problem with the material, it would have been nice if you added a screenshot of the _Shader Editor_ with the domain material as well.